# How to increase spacing between label and tics in gnu plot?

Tags: plot, label, gnuplot, physics, axis-labels

I wanted to increase the font sizes of labels, tics, key-s etc in my plot so increased them using using these commands:

```
set key font ',14';
set tic font ',20';
set xlabel font ',20';
set ylabel font ',20';
```

It got increased but now my y-label and y-tics overlap like this:
[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `help label` and `help margins`.
One way would be to adjust the label offset and the left margin, e.g.

```
set ylabel "Some extra offset" offset -2,0
set lmargin 20
```

Adjust the numbers to your needs.